# Anything other than username in Person or Group column will not resolve only in quick edit mode

Tags: 2010, 2013, column, migration

This is a SharePoint 2013 environment migrated from SharePoint 2010 (this works properly in the old 2010 environment).

There's a “Person or Group” column present in a document library. When using “Quick Edit” on the library, they cannot resolve anything other than a username. Using the preferred name (First, Last) does not resolve. However, when editing a single item (Context Menu -> Edit Properties), the name resolves without issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I faced similar issue earlier. But now, it does resolve by name using the Quick edit.

Comment: Please take a look at this [stackexchange-post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64384/error-on-adding-people-in-sp-2013-datasheet-view) I think it will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is your issue or not but there is a bug in 2013 for using first / last name with , .

Its an ongoing problem. Could be why your getting the username to resolve but not the names themselfs!

as a user noted to microsoft:

> Our Active Directory convention for the  Display Name attribute is
>   "Last Name, First Name". Note the comma in between last and first
>   names.
>
> Our Logon names are based on people’s initials; these are 2, 3, 4 or 5
>   characters long.
>
> In SharePoint 2013, we experience problems in lists, with people
>   picker and with search refiners.  It appears that the comma in the
>   display name is treated as a list separator.
>
> When editing a list with a person field in grid-format, we are
>   experiencing these problems:
>
> •You cannot enter a person through "Last Name, First Name". It throws
>   an error: “The user does not exist or is not unique” Some of our
>   colleagues have no “Last name”, hence no comma in their display and
>   those get validated without problems.
>
> •You cannot copy a validated person with a Fill Down to other rows
>
> •You can't look up a person with the people picker and select from the
>   search results. The selection does not pass validation in the grid,
>   but throws the error that the user does not exist, although it was
>   suggested by the people picker. (We assume that the person is passed
>   from People Picker to Grid component identified via the Display Name
>   string or the Distinguished Name attribute in which the comma is
>   incorrectly interpreted.)
>
> •if you type a person’s "Last Name, First Name" and the First Name
>   corresponds to the Logon initials (DN attribute in AD) of another
>   person, then the other person gets selected.
>
> •In search refiners, people names are shown with 2 comma’s instead of
>   1. “Last Name ,, First Name”

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a55569e7-dcf4-41a4-93fb-62adfc6798fe/people-picker-and-accounts-with-commas?forum=sharepointadmin

there are two resolutions.

1 use a script provided by microsoft to change:

from:

first name , last name

to

first name last name

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/71818859-13ca-42f8-99f9-2783f70984c7/

or

2 use this update:

> Issues that this cumulative update package fixes
>
> •When you assign a task to a user whose display name contains a comma
>   on a SharePoint Server 2013 site, you receive the following error
>   message:
>
> The user does not exist or is not unique.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2825647

also like to note that microsoft are not going to fix the issue as it would compramise other areas but it looks like the hotfix does solve the issue!

Comment: I had tried the AD fix as the display name for users was the default lastname, firstname, I changed it to firstname lastname. This hasn't fixed the issue but I will try the CU. Thank you very much for your response, I wasn't aware that they had addressed this issue in a hotfix finally as a couple of posts about this issue had said Microsoft was NOT planning on fixing this.

Comment: well its a mixed bag tbh.. they did say they were not going to fix it but a hotfix was released partly for this issue even tho they cleary stated that they didnt want to for security reasons? saying that they must of got so many complaints lol

Comment: Yeah, and this totally works in 2010 for that matter. Strange. I'm installing the hotfix now, I'll let you know how it goes. I backed out the AD user display change as well.

Comment: Nice, October CU fixed the issue.

Comment: glad to see that it solves your issue!